# How to close all tooltips defined against the map object?

Tags: leaflet, tooltip

In Leaflet it's possible to bind one or more [tooltips](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tooltip) to an individual marker, or a layer, or the base `map` object.

[image]

How can I close all open tooltips that have been bound to the `map` object?

```
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);
map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

// Define some tooltips against the map object
var tooltip1 = map.openTooltip("tooltip 1",[48.84, 2.34]);
map.openTooltip("tooltip 2",[48.83, 2.33]);
map.openTooltip("tooltip 3",[48.82, 2.32]);

// Attempt to close tooltips, individually or en masse - neither works
map.closeTooltip(tooltip1);
map.closeTooltip();
```

See also the [JS Fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/3v7hd2vx/391/) of the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all layers from your map, and remove them from the map.
To avoid removing the tile layer (background), filter with `if(layer.options.pane === "tooltipPane")`.

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if(layer.options.pane === "tooltipPane") layer.removeFrom(map);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/392/

Comment: ah, I didn't realise that Leaflet creates a separate layer for each tooltip. Nice one!

Comment: Apparently Leaflet creates a new 'hybrid' layer when a tooltip is added directly on the map (not bound to another layer). I think the best way to do it would be to create an invisible marker layer and to bind the tool tip to it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution below.

js:

```
// checked is from a toggle component...
const tooltipPanes = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-tooltip-pane");
if (checked) {
  tooltipPanes[0].classList.remove("tooltip-hidden");
} else {
  tooltipPanes[0].classList.add("tooltip-hidden");
}
```

css:

```
.tooltip-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```